# Why does or ("||") allow the path-sum algorithm to work?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to step through the solution for Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum and can't wrap my head around why the "||" statement allows the function to pass the tests. Is it because it only will continue to invoke the function if we don't return true? Does returning true stop the other recursive calls from occurring? I am just looking for some clarification! Thank y'all.

```
var hasPathSum = function(root, targetSum) {
    if (!root) return false;
    if (targetSum === root.val && !root.left && !root.right) return true;
    return hasPathSum(root.left, targetSum - root.val) || hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum - root.val);
};
```

Comment: `Does returning true stop the other recursive calls from occurring?` Exactly. Look up `short-circuit Boolean evaluation` for more information.

Comment: If you explicitly *do not* want the expression to be short-circuited you have to use the other operator, "|" (a single pipe). "|" is called "logical OR operator" and "||" is called "conditional logical OR operator" (and is used more often in code).